# Is my question now acceptable for this website?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[My question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348145/question-about-the-operating-of-forces-in-a-physics-problem) was put on hold a short time ago and I made some changes in my question (after considering feedback from other users) to make it more suitable for Physics Stack Exchange.

Could any experienced users let me know if my question is now a good fit for the website? I want to learn how I can use this platform in the best possible way and constructive feedback will be help me meet this objective.

EDIT:

Please let me know what is CURRENTLY wrong with my question. I looked at the [good questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and framed my question according to the pattern followed by those questions. So I don't see why my question is STILL not suitable for this website.